# create a function with specific parameter types

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, jsdoc

I'm making a Google Apps Script function that takes two parameters: a Spreadsheet object and a Transaction object, which I created. How can I specify that I want my parameters to have that type?

I'm looking for this functionality:

```
function addTransaction(Spreadsheet sheet,Transaction t){//blah blah blah doesn't matter}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Also add more details of the IDE that you are using and if you are open to use another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript which is not a statically typed language. You can't enforce types. You will need to manually check the types in your function body.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSDoc syntax to show hints, like this.
(not sure what Transaction means, but hope you get the idea)

```
/**
 * @param {SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet} sheet
 * @param {Transaction} t
 */
function addTransaction(sheet, t){ blah blah}
```

See here or more details: https://jsdoc.app/tags-param